# How to get System Services running under (Services.msc) in c#

Tags: c#, .net, service

I have a requirement that i want to get all the system services running under system which will display the Services either in the Started or in Stopped.

How can i achieve this in C# using ASP.Net.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to use:

```
ServiceController[] services = ServiceController.GetServices();
```

There is also overload that accept computer name if you want to get the list on a remote computer.

```
ServiceController[] services = ServiceController.GetServices("SomeComputerName");
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.getservices.aspx

Comment: How to get the remote computer services

Comment: @VaraPrasad.M you just need to put your remote server name

Answer (score 2):

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1008/NET-Diagnostics-III-Enumerate-System-Services-and

Answer (score 0):

@Vara Prasad.M: First of all add system.serviceprocess reference then

<<********** Here is a code to check service status **********>>

```
 ServiceController[] services = ServiceController.GetServices();
foreach(Service ser in services )
{
  if(ser.Status==ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
   {
        Response.Write("Service is running");
   }
   else
    {
        Response.Write("Service is stopped");
    }
}
```

Comment: The above is the one where we can get the local system. but if i want to get the remote system then how can i achieve it?

Comment: try doing ServiceController.GetServices(machineName) (machinename whos services you are going to look)

Comment: If i am giving the ipaddress in ServiceController.GetServices("192.XXX.XX.XX") then i am getting the error message as "The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found" How to resolve this issue???

Comment: check this link if it helps you http://www.go4expert.com/forums/showthread.php?t=19281